# How to change path to credentials file (without environment variable)

Tags: scala, sbt

I currently set path to a credentials file like this:

```
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".myfolder" / "my.credentials")
```

on my local computer this works because `Path.userHome` results in `~`. However, on Jenkins `Path.userHome` results in `/root` and I'm unable to create `.myfolder` under `/root` at build time because I get a permission denied error.

I am trying to change the path to the credentials file to `/home/jenkins/.myfolder/my.credentials`. However, when I do

```
credentials += Credentials("/home/jenkins/.myfolder/my.credentials")
```

I get a runtime error because apply method for `Credentials` accepts java.io.File.

**Question**

- How can I pass in `/home/jenkins/.myfolder/my.credentials` to `Credentials`?

Answer (score 2):

If it expects a File, then look at [the File docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-) to see how to make one.

```
credentials += Credentials(new java.io.File("/home/jenkins/.myfolder/my.credentials"))
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand Brian McCutchon's answer further:

According to SBT's [Path.scala](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/sxr/Path.scala.html) source, the `Path.userHome` returns a `java.io.File` and Path contains an implicit method `implicit def richFile(file: File): RichFile = new RichFile(file)` to convert File to RichFile.

And, the slash operator (`/`) is overloaded for RichFile types to create objects of `java.io.File` with appended string path.

Hence, if we want to pass a standalone string without a `RichFile` or `File` as a path to the `Credentials` constructor which requires a `java.io.File` instance as a parameter, we need to specifically create a `java.io.File` object with the string path, like, `File("path/to/file")`

Comment: In that same source file is the `def apply(f: String)` which, to me, looks like the simplest solution: `Credentials(Path("/path/to/file"))`